# Set ComputerName Enviornment Variable

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I need to use a VBS script to set the environment variable %computername% to "blah".  This seems like a simple enough task but for some reason I'm finding it difficult this morning.  I can do this via a command prompt (set computername=blah) and I can get the value of the environment variable via VBS but I cant seem to find the correct syntax to override the environment variable.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you create it determines its type and lifetime. If you want the variable to be available until the user logs off, you can create it as `VOLATILE`.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Environment("VOLATILE")("MyVariable") = "This is some data to share"
```

And to read it back...

```
strValue = objShell.Environment("VOLATILE")("MyVariable")
```

Other options for the variable's type are `SYSTEM`, `USER`, and `PROCESS`. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156595.aspx) for a nice article describing the differences.

Comment: That seems really close to what i'm needing, but when I pull up a command prompt and type echo %computername% I still get the name of my computer.  Is there a way to override that variable?

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of the computer? Because changing the environmental variable is not the way to go about it. I just did `objShell.Environment("PROCESS")("COMPUTERNAME") = "NEW"` and it worked.

Comment: well like I said if i open a command prompt i can type set computername=blah and then if i do an echo %computername% it prints "blah"  I need to do that same thing just with a VBS script.  I'm using thinapp and one of the programs that I have thinapp'd looks at the computer, so if i can trick it into thinking its on the old computer I think it should help solve a lot of problems

Comment: I just did some more testing and it looks like you have to set both the `SYSTEM` and `USER` ones. And then it takes a few seconds but the variable is updated.

Comment: what did you use for "MyVariable", i'm using computername?

Comment: Right. I used `objShell.Environment("SYSTEM")("COMPUTERNAME") = "NEW"`, followed by `objShell.Environment("USER")("COMPUTERNAME") = "NEW"` and it updated my `COMPUTERNAME` variable.